# How to get bounding box around objects?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors, 3d

I have coordinates for different geometric shapes like rhombus, polygon, rectangle and etc. I need exact coordinates for bounding box around them. My coordinates for points 1,2,3,4 & 5 can start from clockwise or anticlockwise. But bounding box should be accurate. How can I get the coordinates for the rectangle around the shapes?
[image]

Best example I can give is the link below. Draw any shape on the map using polygon tool in this below link and you will get the rectangle around it. So I need coordinates for this rectangle.
[Link here](https://boundingbox.klokantech.com/)

**Example coordinates for 1 polygon:**

(x1,y1) = (8.375, 127.5258)
(x2,y2) = (26.1326, 127.5258)
(x3,y3) = (26.375,  130.5258)
(x4,y4) = (23.6995, 141.2277)
(x5,y5) = (8.375,   137.3966)

Comment: does taking minimum and maximum of both coordinates work?

Comment: If you know where one point is $(x,y)$, you could likely use a plethora of triangles to find the other points in relation to $(x,y)$

Comment: Are your shapes convex? Are the boxes with horizontal and vertical edges? That probably matters for an answer

Comment: @Taladris  Shape can be convex or concave too. Yes boxes are horizontal and vertical edges. If you draw any shape on the map Link I gave above. Exactly I need box like that. So I need coordinates for that rectangle.

Comment: @JosephEck how can I generate new coordinates to create triangles which finally makes it a box.

Answer (score 0):

For an $n$-gone you have
$$x_{\text{min}} = \min \{ x_k \mid k = 1, \ldots, n \}$$
and similar for $x_{\text{max}}, y_{\text{min}}, y_{\text{max}}, z_{\text{min}}, z_{\text{max}}.$

In pseudo-code:

```
x_min := +inf
x_max := -inf
y_min := +inf
y_max := -inf
z_min := +inf
z_max := -inf

for p in corners:
    x_max = max(x_max, p.x)
    x_min = min(x_min, p.x)
    y_max = max(y_max, p.y)
    y_min = min(y_min, p.y)
    z_max = max(z_max, p.z)
    z_min = min(z_min, p.z)
end for
```

Comment: I have x_max, x_min, y_max, y_min but how to trace p.x, p.y?

Comment: During one lap of the `for` loop, `p` is one of the corners of the polygon: $(x_1, y_1), \ldots, (x_n, y_n)$, and `p.x` refers to the $x$ coordinate and `p.y` refers to the $y$ coordinate. For example, if `p` refers to $(26.1326, 127.5258)$ then `p.x` is $26.1326$ and `p.y` is $127.5258$.